# How to tell what OpenSSL version was built with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ssl

When I do `ffmpeg -version`, I get this:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
configuration: --enable-openssl
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
```

It says `--enable-openssl`, but how can I check what version of SSL was it specifically built with?

Comment: And if you are using a Mac, please add an OS tag to questions. (That's always a good idea, even if not using a Mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see which version it **links** to:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep ssl
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb5ae8000)
```

And then you can check with whatever package manager you distro uses what version of openssl this library belongs to.

Comment: Won't this get the *installed* version rather than the *compiled* one?

Comment: @harrymc It will get the version it was dynamically linked to when it was *compiled* (note the `1.0.0`, which is the ABI). Since it is *dynamically* compiled, that's as close as you can get to "the version it was compiled with" just looking at the binary. There are not other traces of the "version it was compiled with" in the binary except the dynamic reference.

Comment: I used `otools -L` instead of `ldd`, quick research shows that `ldd` is basically linux's version of `otools`